# Leetcode 'NoneType' Object Has No Attribute 'Next'

Tags: python, linked-list

I was working on [this](https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-linked-lists/) problem, and I was getting an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next'
```

Could someone help point me in the right direction?

```
# Definition for singly-linked list.
# class ListNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.next = None

class Solution:
    def getIntersectionNode(self, headA: ListNode, headB: ListNode) -> ListNode:

        while (True):
            headA = headA.next      # advance '1' step in list_A {this is the error line}

            if (headA == headB):    # check for equality
                return headA

            headB = headB.next      # advance '1' step in list_B
```

Comment: When you reach the tail of the list (the last node), `node.next` is going to be `None`, so you need to handle this case.

Comment: Please post the full error and an actual [mre]. Your current code doesn't raise any error, it is just defining a class...

Answer (score 0):

The error is obtained when you have reached the end of the linked list i.e. when `headA` is `None`.